# Emission Spectra Light Wavelength Deviations for Mercury

Tags: light, mercury, emission

The Problem: Inconsistencies between the measured and true values of mercury's spectra light wavelengths emitted following a laboratory experiment.

**What I Know:** The experiment conducted was viewing the colors and distances of emitted lights, through a grating, from a sample of mercury in a transformer. Purple, green, and orange were determined correctly to be the spectral light colors of mercury and the wavelengths for each must be found in centimeters. The formula $\lambda = d  \sin(\arctan((x / y))$ is required, where $d = 1/5.3 \times 10^3$ with regards to the constant distance between the grating grooves, $x = (x1 + x2) / 2$ with regards to the average x-axis length from the transformer, and $y = 99.9$ with regards to the constant y-axis length from the transformer.

**Failed Calculation:** The x-axis length averages were determined to be 9.25, 11.63, and 12.75 centimeters for purple, green, and orange correspondingly. After plugging the values into the formula, it resulted in wavelengths of $\pu{1.74e-5}$, $\pu{2.18e-5}$, and $\pu{2.39e-5}$ centimeters. However, the true wavelengths are $\pu{4.35e-5}$, $\pu{5.46e-5}$, and $\pu{5.77e-5}$ centimeters.

**Attempted Fixes:** I have already checked the data collected alongside formula input, and the formulas are what must be used when solving for the wavelengths.

With a percent error of about 60%, I do not understand how I am finding mercury's wavelengths wrong with the given formulas or what I am missing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Experiment Diagram:

[image]

Comment: @Ed V The diagram for the experiment has been added, and that is exactly how we conducted it. I just do not understand how the wavelengths are correctly deduced from the spectra light data. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The grating groove distance was initially in mm, but was converted to cm and is a constant $ 1 / 5.30 * 10^3$. Your diagram is basically how we conducted the experiment as well, and the formula is the same. I am doing something wrong with the calculations here though, I just don't know what. Again, thank you @Ed V for your time.

Comment: Those values though are very close to the true values. There may be an error in the grating distance, but with regards to an assumption of 200 lines/mm, for purple I tried to reproduce the plugging in you used as so: $λ = 200 * sin(tan^-1(9.25* 10^8 / 9.99 * 10^8))$. The result was 18.1 nm, different from 461 nm. How did you plug in your values in the equation, as my mistakes in that might also contribute to the percent error?

Comment: That conversion worked. That is all I guess, as assuming the distance as 5000 nm seems to get close to the true values and it might just be a grating length error. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Matt if you have found the answer to your question it is always okay to post answer to it. This 1) helps future readers know the question has been answered (many people don't read comments, they don't usually end up in web searches) and 2) you may pick up some additional reputation points. Once you reach 50 you can start leaving comments under other people's posts for example; privileges continue to open up as your reputation points increase. *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*